# Dark Emission when using MixRGB with Colour and Image

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders

I am trying to overlay an image over an object so that the background colour does not change, but the image is overlayed on top. My Image was created on Inkscape and exported with no transparency so I don't think it is an alpha problem. I am getting a grey tint over the Pink background colour that I cannot seem to remove. Any suggestions?

[edit] Blender version 2.8

[image: Kirby Image taken by me]

Comment: Are you using Eevee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should plug the alpha output of your image texture into the alpha input of the principled BSDF, then use the color output directly in the color input of the BSDF.

Make sure to check the blend mode to something else than "opaque" in the settings of the material. Press N to open the panel when in the shading node editor then go to Options>Settings>Blend Mode. Depending on your blender version you might have to try different ones to achieve your goal.